# How to handle multiple submit buttons in NextJS?

Tags: html, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to create a form component in nextjs with two submit buttons in it. I'm having issues with determining which button was pressed. How can I solve this?

```
import React from "react";

const LoginPage = () => {
  async function handleSubmit(data: FormData) {
    "use server";

  }

  return (
    <form className="relative w-full" action={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-3 relative w-full items-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="relative border-2 w-5/6 p-2 rounded-md indent-2 font-bold border-slate-400"
          placeholder="Username"
          name="username"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          className="relative border-2 w-5/6 p-2 rounded-md indent-2 font-bold border-slate-400"
          placeholder="Password"
          name="password"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 mt-5 items-center">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="py-3 px-6 rounded-2xl font-bold bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-400 outline outline-2 hover:text-white hover:outline-black"
          name="loginButton"
        >
          Login
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="py-3 px-6 rounded-2xl font-bold bg-slate-100 hover:bg-slate-400 outline outline-2 hover:text-white hover:outline-black"
          name="registerButton"
        >
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

I need to be able to determine which button was pressed (login/register) and have the handleSubmit() run it's code accordingly. Thanks in advance.

I'm looking for a way to differentiate between the login and register buttons. I'm fairly new to NextJS so I cannot think of a way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe you can use [submitter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) property? But keep in mind, that the `submit` event can be triggered in other ways than pressing a button, for example by pressing Enter while one of form fields is in focus.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djSOx.png)

if you log your data in server function,
it should have `action`, `add-to-cart`

if you set your submit button to:

```
<button
  name="action"
  value="add-to-cart"
  type="submit"
  Add to Cart
</button>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works in a server action you can get the formData.get() method to access the name and then you're able to use the data. Thanks!